# Extracted variable name dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to extract a variable name from a data frame a create a new variable with dplyr::mutate.
What do I have to write so that the variable name provided through "md$meta[1]" is accepted?
I think this is straight forward but I haven't been able to find the answer on the web.
Any help greatly appreciated!

## Fake data

```
iris <- head(iris)
meta <- c("a", "b", "c")
data <- c(1:3)
md <- data.frame(meta, data)
rm(meta, data)
```

## Desired output

```
iris <- iris %>%
  mutate("a" = md$data[1])
```

## Code attempt

```
iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(paste0(md$meta[1]) = md$data[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with assignment (`:=`) and by evaluating (`!!`) the lhs of the assignment

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(!! paste0(md$meta[1]) := md$data[1])
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species a
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 1
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 1
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 1
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 1
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 1
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 1
```